# Handling output of python socket recv

Tags: python, sockets

Apologies for the noob Python question but I've been stuck on this for far too long.

I'm using python sockets to receive some data from a server. I do this:

```
data = self.socket.recv(4)
print "data is ", data
print "repr(data) is ", repr(data)
```

The output on the console is this:

> data is 
>   repr(data) is  '\x00\x00\x00\x01'

I want to turn this string containing essentially a 4 byte number into an int - or actually what would be a long in C. How can I turn this data object into a numerical value that I can easily manage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to use [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#module-struct).

The code would look something like:

```
import struct

data = self.socket.recv(4)
print "data is ", data
print "repr(data) is ", repr(data)
myint = struct.unpack("!i", data)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually had to do "myint = unpack("!i", data)[0]" since it's big-endian and it comes out as a tuple. If you want to edit I'll mark your answer correct. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Missed the tuple part. :) Edited the answer per your request.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, I believe the last line should also be:  myint = struct.unpack("!i", data)[0]